# Xamarin iOS - Issue referencing a UIView from a custom UITableViewCell class

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I would like to create a simple animation when a view is tapped within a cell.When this view is tapped, I would like to change it's color to blue, and slide it to the right of screen.

I have two challenges:

1. How do I reference the exact view that was tapped?

Currently, more than one view is changed to blue, not even the one that was tapped, when I expect just the tapped view to change.

2. The view does not slide/hide.This is an information overlay. I'd like to hide it by sliding it to the right if it's drawn out(in order to hide the information) and then slide it back to the left to display the info when the user taps on it again. Basically an open/close animation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (CustomCell.Key) as CustomCell;

        if (cell == null) {

            cell = new CustomCell ();

        }

        try
        {
            cell.cellImageView.Image = TableItems[indexPath.Row];

            tapOnOverlay = new UITapGestureRecognizer(HideTheOverlay);
            cell.overlay.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
            cell.overlay.AddGestureRecognizer(tapOnOverlay);

    }
        catch (Exception imageException)
        {
            Console.Write(imageException.Message);
        }

        return cell;
    }


 public void HideTheOverlay()
    {
        try{

            UIView.Animate(2.0,()=> {

// How do I get a reference to the exact view that was tapped on here??

cell.overlay.Layer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue.CGColor;

// This does not move the view. Nothing happens here

cell.overlay.Layer.Frame = new RectangleF(
                        new PointF((float)cell.overlay.Layer.Frame.Location.X + 200, 
                            (float)cell.overlay.Layer.Frame.Location.Y),
                        (SizeF)cell.overlay.Frame.Size);


            });

        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);

        }
```

Comment: Not sure if it's the root of your problem but do you realize if the cell is reused you will end with more than one gesture recoginzer?

Comment: That's true. I hadn't realized that. All I am trying to do is animate a view that exists within a custom cell. How do I go about it using best practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem above.

I passed the `UITapGestureRecognizer` as a parameter in my `HideOverlay` function and thus to get the selected/tapped view, I accessed it by calling the `View` property from the gesture recognizer. From there, I could animate the view according by accessing the view's `Layer`.

Below is the full implementation of my open/close animation

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        CustomCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (CustomCell.Key) as CustomeCell;

        if (cell == null) {

            cell = new CustomCell ();

        }
            tapOnOverlay = new UITapGestureRecognizer(HideTheOverlay);
            cell.overlay.AddGestureRecognizer(tapOnOverlay);
            cell.overlay.UserInteractionEnabled = true;

       catch (Exception imageException)
        {
            Console.Write(imageException.Message);
        }

        return cell;
    }
```

**The HideOverlay function**

```
     public void HideTheOverlay(UITapGestureRecognizer tap)
    {
        try{

            UIView.Animate(1.5,()=> {

                float offsetXClose = (float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width - ((float)tap.View.Layer.Frame.Location.X + 20);

                float offsetXOpen = (float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width - ((float)tap.View.Layer.Frame.Width);


                float currentXPosition = (float)tap.View.Layer.Frame.Location.X;

                float finalXPosition = currentXPosition + offsetXClose;


                if(currentXPosition == finalXPosition) //Means the overlay is already closed. We should open it
                {

                    //Open the overlay by moving it to the left
                    tap.View.Layer.Frame = new RectangleF(
                        new PointF((float)tap.View.Layer.Frame.Location.X - offsetXOpen, 
                            (float)tap.View.Layer.Frame.Location.Y),
                        (SizeF)tap.View.Frame.Size);

                }else{

                    //Close the overlay, by moving it to the right
                    tap.View.Layer.Frame = new RectangleF(
                        new PointF((float)tap.View.Layer.Frame.Location.X + offsetXClose, 
                            (float)tap.View.Layer.Frame.Location.Y),
                        (SizeF)tap.View.Frame.Size);
                }


            });

        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);

        }

    }
```